# How to run GoogleAppEngineLauncher in terminal window(Google cloud SDK shell)?

Tags: google-app-engine, sdk

Google no longer support the GoogleAppEngineLauncher program.

When I installed GoogleAppEngine I just got Google Cloud SDK shell. I want to add a project to GoogleAppEngine to run and deploy.

I got these links and cant understand

- [Local Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server)
- [Deploying the Application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/deploying-the-application)

How to do it both locally and online ?

Comment: Could you confirm if you are running it in Windows or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Quickstart for Windows"](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-windows) is a good starting point for new users of Cloud SDK.

In order to deploy and run a GAE application with the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) you have to use shell/command prompt, as opposed to GoogleAppEngineLauncher where you had a GUI. The steps are:

1. Open the shell
2. In the shell change the current directory to where your project's `app.yaml`.  is. For example: `CD C:\Users\AQueue\Projects\MyGAEApplication` and check that `app.yaml` file is there using `dir` command.
3. run [`gcloud app deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy)

This should be it.

`gcloud` is one of the most important tools in the SDK that allows to interact with many products and services from Google Cloud Platform. If you want to read more about `gcloud` you can start with this [overview](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/).